# SKPolyline is not rendered with spacing on iOS

Tags: ios, skmaps

I'd like to draw SKPolyline dashed. I know it's possible with SKPolygon with **borderDotsSize** and **borderDotsSpacingSize** params. As they both are defined in common parent for SKPolyline and SKPolygon - SKOverlay i think that drawing dashed SKPolyline should be possible. However it simply does not work. So my question is - does it work for someone?

I'm using 2.3 SDK.

Relevant code:

```
SKPolyline *polyline = [[SKPolyline alloc] init];
polyline.coordinates = coordinates;
polyline.lineWidth = 10;
polyline.fillColor = fillColor;
polyline.borderDotsSize = 5;
polyline.borderDotsSpacingSize = 5;
[self.skMapView addPolyline:polyline];
[polyline release];
```

Comment: Would updating to a newer SDK version be an option? (i.e. 2.5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Make the following settings and you should get the expected result:

`polyline.lineWidth = 0;
 polyline.backgroundLineWidth=10;`